# Remove padding beneath heading tag

Tags: html, css

Currently I have a list that has an H3 heading above it (which I can't really remove easily, it's auto generated by a cms) and looks something like this

```
Headline
|
|
List stuff
```

and I want to get rid of the pipes.  They seem to be "built in" to the `<h3>` tag, anyone have any idea what CSS property of h3 would get rid of this?

Comment: can you post the relevant source of the `h3`?

Comment: What is the style that is current applied to `<h3>` elements?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

H1, H2, and H3 tags all inherently have a margin and padding added to them by browsers.

You can test this by putting a background on the H1, H2, and H3 tags in css and looking in different browsers.

To remove the "pipe spacing" you should:

```
h3{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Then you can re-add whatever you would like since CSS is a one-way execution path.  Consequent CSS values will overwrite base-level CSS.

Comment: That was it, thanks!  I had tried the padding but not the margin.  I should have guessed that when the background didn't extend but I could see it when I used firebug.

Thanks!

Comment: In`R leaflet`, I wanted to remove padding below headers like h1, h2, ... in a label or popup. I used your answer + **inline** styling: m <- leaflet() %>% # leaflet works with the pipe operator
  addTiles() %>% addMarkers(data = df , ~Long, ~Lat,
               popup = ~paste(paste(**"<h3 style='padding:0px; margin:0px'>"**,Company,"</h3>"), Address))

Answer (score 14):

Another option that removes the space below the text is as follows:

```
h3 
{ 
    display:inline; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the "border" style property on the H3 to

```
border:0;
```

It's possible that the "pipe" is actually a border on the headline, a border-right property, that you can modify or override.

Alternative: A true pipe that the CMS generates (I'm assuming you've checked the HTML source and this is not the case, but good to ask)

Can you select the text and see if it is a true pipe character, or rather just a visual element?

Other Alternative: Some kind of CSS content property. More rare, since most browsers don't support it.

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to @Jonathan answer, You must add:

```
p{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the pipes are actual text, you're not going to be able to get rid of them without using some form of JavaScript.

If the pipes are a background image for the H3, you can use this to get rid of them:

```
h3
{
  background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set height according to your requirement along with font size and it will remove the padding if the height is lesser than the font size takes!