# Css remove empty space in h tags

Tags: html, css, html-head

Is any way to remove empty space in top of the `h` tags?

```css
h1 {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test Title yg</h1>
```

[image]

Comment: this space is needed for character like `ÂÄ`

Comment: Every font contains default lineheight,  when you remove the top or bottom space then fetch problem when 2 or more line break.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove padding beneath H3 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235134/remove-padding-beneath-h3-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking for :

```css
h1 {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test Title yg</h1>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for!
But this space is needed for HTML special characters.
Please have a look at HTML characters [here](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~svb/chars.html)

Comment: Yes i understand. For example `İ, Ğ, Ü, Ö` or smt. this space is required. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The space above the text depends on the type of font and the size of the font you are using. When using large font size, it's bound to show some extra space at the top and bottom of the text. You can set the `margin-top` of `h1` tags to -10px or something to adjust for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line-height: calc(1em + 2px);` to remove some space, but there is a reason why the space is available. On the bottom of "g" and "y" there is some space to the border. With the `line-height: calc(1em + 2px);` you can remove this space but not the space above "T". There can be characters like `ÄÖÜ` (in german) who need some space above and characters like `gyq` who need some space below.

```css
h1 {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: calc(1em + 2px);
}
```

```html
<h1>Test Title yg</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Top and Bottom space it's actually come from font-family, but you can remove top space by change `line-height: normal;` to `line-height: 1.4rem;`. I hope it'll work for you. Thanks

```
h1 {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
}
<h1>Test Title yg</h1>
```